# Gestalt druid/monk, can you use feral combat training to make flurry with slam attacks?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, druid, monk, gestalt

I am building a gestalt character using druid and monk. I saw in another post about using [feral combat training and natural attacks](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/70949/monks-natural-and-unarmed-attacks-and-feral-combat-training). The linked question gave me the following idea.

My character will be wild shaping into elemental forms and dealing increased damage due to their increased size. Elementals all have a slam attack. A slam attack is a natural attack which means that [FCT](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/feral-combat-training-combat/) can be used on it. My thought was that if I take FCT on the slam attack, I could use the slam attack with flurry of blows and thus gain multiple uses of the slam attack in a round.

Is this possible?

Comment: Unchained monk or regular?

Comment: @KRyan In theory it shouldnt matter? But regular and Im going to be using it with zen archer as well, hehehe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is possible; that is literally the stated purpose of Feral Combat Training.